# Python AtributeError: __enter__ when using urlopen in `with as` statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I'm trying to understand why the use of 'with as' statement with urlopen generate this  exception in my code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

AttributeError: __enter__
```

This is the code:

```
%%time
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

url = input('Enter - ')
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
with urlopen(req).read() as html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    nums = []
    table = soup.find('table')
    table_data = table.find_all('span')
    for data in table_data:
        nums.append(int(data.text))
    print(sum(nums))
```

And why I removed the tab from the last line, it no longer generates the error.

```
print(sum(nums))
```

Comment: You're calling `read`. Maybe put `with urlopen(req) as response:` and then `html = response.read()`

Comment: Look at the context manager example in the documentation. It uses ```with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f: print(f.read(100).decode('utf-8'))```